# jQuery+jQueryUI Vs Yahoo UI..Which is the best one for web applications?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, user-interface, yahoo

jQuery+jQueryUI vs Yahoo UI..Which is the best UI to use in asp.net web applications?

Comment: Your question is quite subjective. What do you mean by best?

Comment: -1 Becuase polls are not welcome.
@Delan: Don't be childish. This is not the wanted behavior we encourage and seek here.

Comment: in all aspects.like performnce..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is a little open-ended to be answered in a single answer.

I think in this case the answer must be there are horses-for-courses.  By that I mean you need to choose the right technology to suit the problem you are trying to solve.

You have not provided us with enough information to make a critical judgment on your needs.  All you have asked is which is better and the answer is neither.  They both fit a need.  They overlap in a great many places but each also has it's own unique advantages.

So I guess you need to either provide us with more information on what problem you are trying to solve or gain an in-depth understanding of both technologies to see which best fits your solution.  It may be that you need both or you may decide to role your own.

If you have a particular issue then please create a new question with the particulars and perhaps someone will be better placed in giving you an answer.

However, having said all that, I'm a huge fan of jQuery.  It's easy to use and lightweight.  I can very quickly and easily write my own plugins and there is a great community out there sharing their own plugins.

I can't speak for the Yahoo UI as I haven't used it in quite some time and at the moment when I begin a new project I instantly reach for jQuery.  But that's my own personal, and possibly subjective, choice.